# Is it possible to save except for indexing specific fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The json data is stored in the elasticsearch. However, the type of the specific field of the data is not one but two or more types. So, if save it, I got a type error because of the stored other type data first.

I want to store the raw data without changing the data type. Is it possible to save except for the indexing of certain fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the indexing of specific fields with the [enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) option. But this option can only be used at the root of the mapping or on "object" fields.

An other way is to set `dynamic` mapping to `false` for this index (documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html)), and manually create the mapping for the only fields you want to index.